# How do I get a java applet signed?

Tags: java, applet, certificate, digital-signature

So, I have this website that contains a java applet (before you insult me, no, I can't replace it with HTML5/JS, I am not responsible for this), but the latest java update prevents websites from running self signed applets.
Of course my applet is self signed, so how do I "get it signed"?

Comment: You might also consider packaging your program up as a desktop application using something like Launch4j, JarSplice, or JWrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can have a look at the following :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/security.html

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/appletwarning-135102.html

Comment: so basically I have to get my signature signed by a CA, and pay for it? that applet's going straight in the bin

Comment: Yes, this is going to cost you money.

Comment: nice way to promote their technology. i guess i'll get rid of the applet

Comment: Well in a way yes. You can have a look at the following : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/signedJNLP.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/settingArgsProperties.html